# Remove certain indexes from 2d array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Firstname one
            [2] => Lastname one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Firstname two
            [2] => Lastname two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Firstname three
            [2] => Lastname three
        )
)
```

Now, I would like to remove the entire `index 1`, i.e., all the firstname's from the array. I was planning on using `array_splice` by looping through the entire array and removing its index 1. But is there a better way. (I want the re-indexing after deletion of elements.)

Comment: If you want to reindex it, I would also go with `array_splice()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourarray = array_map(function($el) {
  unset($el[1]); //remove index 1
  return array_values($el); //return and reindex
}, $yourarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `array_slice` function like

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
    array_splice($v, 1,1);
    $array[$k] = $v;
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Lastname one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Lastname two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Lastname three
        )

)
```

Comment: Your method works fine but gives  `Warning: array_splice() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given`

Comment: i dint get this type of warning and also and make sure you are passing "$v" as array as first parameter in array_splice()

Answer (score 1):

You should use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$input_array = [[1,'Firstname one','Lastname one'],
                [2,'Firstname two','Lastname two'],
                [3,'Firstname three','Lastname three']];

$resultArray = array_map(function($record) { 
  return [$record[0], $record[2]]; // add your desired records
}, $input_array);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultArray);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Lastname one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Lastname two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Lastname three
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
    unset($array[$k][1]); /// Chnage the key of array which you want to remove
}
```

Comment: You iterate by `$k` index but unseting always `$i` which is not even incrementing.

Comment: This will not work. You can use $k instead of $i. still some logic needs to implement to get desire output.